# Solve the following equation for x

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Solve the following equation for x

$$10^{\log_{10} {\sqrt2}} - e^{\ln4} = {\sqrt2}{x^2} - 10^{\log_{10} x} -3$$

Comment: Is it $10^{\log_{10}\sqrt2}$

Comment: We have $a^{\log_ay}=y$

Comment: yes I assumed that people knew that it was base 10 when no base was given. I learned if no base was given its always base 10.

Comment: To mathematicians, $\log$ generally means $\ln$ when no base is given.

Comment: @sulinski0923: unless you talk to people for whom $\log$ is $\ln$ by default. But when both appear in the same equation, there is no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

As You said in the comment..So the question is equivalent to
$$\sqrt2-4=\sqrt2x^2-x-3$$

A $(a^{\log_bc})=c^{\log_ba}$

So your equation is 
$$2x^2-\sqrt2x+(\sqrt2-2)=0$$
Using quadratic formula gives the solution....

$$\frac{\sqrt2\pm\sqrt{18-2(\sqrt32)}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt2\pm(4-\sqrt2)}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use that $$a^{\log_a b}=b$$

and then your equation becomes:

$$\sqrt{2}-4=\sqrt{2}x^2-x-3\to \sqrt{2}x^2-x+1-\sqrt{2}=0$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Would you mind solving it out so that I know how to do it for future problems?

Comment: @sulinski0923: That is just a quadratic equation. Use Baskara's formula.